# Analysing point attributes within polygons

Tags: qgis, select-by-location, select-by-expression

I'm using QGIS 3.4.4. 
I have a polygon layer and a points layer. The points have the attributes `district` and `streetname`.

How can a check if all the points within a polygon have the same `district` and `streetname`?

Comment: Have you tried this, in the Select by expression field: 'streetnames' == or = 'district' ?

Comment: Please explain, my question is have all the pointobjects in the same polygon the same streetname or district. So some combination of location and expressions.

Comment: I wrote a python script that selects each polygon if points in it have different `district` or `street` name. You OK with that or do you prefer different solution?

Comment: Thanks, that's OK for me, please profide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Python script.  Copy the script to QGIS Python Editor, change the layer names.

This script finds points in polygon, creates a set containing (`district`, `streetname`) pairs from these points and checks length of the set. If not 1, it selects that polygon. Because, in this case, at least one `streetname` or `district` is different than others.
If all pairs are the same, then length of the set will be 1.

I recommend you first to create spatial index using "Vector general > Create spatial index" tool for both point and polygon layers.

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import qApp 

point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("AdresSectieNN")[0]
polygon_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("PCPlus")[0]

qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().clearWidgets()
messageBar = qgis.utils.iface.messageBar()
progress = QProgressBar()
progress.setMaximum(polygon_layer.featureCount()) 
messageBar.pushWidget(progress)

for i, pol in enumerate(polygon_layer.getFeatures()):
    # create a set
    x = {(p["Sectie"], p["straatnaam"]) for p in point_layer.getFeatures()
                if p.geometry().within(pol.geometry())}    
    # if set (x) has 1 element, it means all points have the same district name and street name
    if len(x) != 1:
        polygon_layer.select(pol.id())

    # set current progress
    progress.setValue(i+1)
    qApp.processEvents()

iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kadir, I need some time to study this.

Comment: I was not succesful:
I paste the following code in the script editor


point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("AdresSectieNN")[0]
polygon_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("PCPlus")[0]

for pol in polygon_layer.getFeatures():    
    # create a set
    x = {(p["Sectie"], p["straatnaam"]) for p in point_layer.getFeatures()
                if p.geometry().within(pol.geometry())}    
    # if set (x) has 1 element, it means all points have the same district name and street name
    if len(x) != 1:
        polygon_layer.select(pol.id())


Responding error

Comment: Sorry for poor layout, don't know how to do it better in 5 minutes edit time
I stopped the script after 10 minutes Not Responding

Comment: How many points are there in point layer? If you have large point dataset, try to run this script on small dataset.

Comment: What is `qApp` ?

Comment: @Taras  I use it usually to prevent freezing of QGIS during long operation (especially in ` for` loop). [This link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) gives detailed information.

Comment: The point layer has 6771 features and the polygon layer has 7403 features.

Comment: Very usefull the progress bar to something is running.
It took 35 minutes to run. I'm evaluating the results.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a virtual layer to create a summary table.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Replace the layer name for yours

```sql
SELECT poly.id, pt.district, pt.streetname, count(*)
FROM my_polygon_layer poly
    JOIN my_point_layer pt ON st_intersects(poly.geometry, pt.geometry)
GROUP BY poly.id, pt.district, pt.streetname
```

If you only want to identify polygons having several districts/points, you can refine the query:

```sql
SELECT id, count(*) as cnt_diff
FROM (
    SELECT poly.id, pt.district, pt.streetname, count(*) as cnt_same
    FROM my_polygon_layer poly
        JOIN my_point_layer pt ON st_intersects(poly.geometry, pt.geometry)
    GROUP BY poly.id, pt.district, pt.streetname
)
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you JGH, I need some time to study this.

Comment: I was not succesful with your SQL code.
I corrected the GROUP BY statement by removing ",count(*)" because I got an error.
After correcting and press Test, QGis did not answer (Not Responding) after 10 minutes.

Comment: @Jan good catch, I have edited the code accordingly. It should work though. If you are running it on a large dateset, or on very large polygons (country size), it might be slow (and since you have the same issue with Kadir's solution it might very well be the case). In this case you will want to use a database with indexed field/geometries and eventually on subdivided polygons

Comment: The point layer has 6771 features and the polygon layer has 7403 features. Not a country size at all.